# Adding numbers with coefficients in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Consider three cells that contain 1+2n, 2+1n, and 3+7n. I want to add these numbers so that I get 6+10n. How can I do that?

**Edit**

I found out that I can use imaginary numbers and then use `IMSUM` to add those imaginary numbers, which needs letter `i` rather than `n`. However, is there a more general way that does not need the imaginary number approach?

Comment: That may be the simplest approach, and is quite clever, IMHO. Another approach, which might be handy in the case of multiple, different types (eg `1+2n+3c; 4+6a+1n+2c`) would involve splitting each string by the delimiter, processing each type; then putting the string back together.  How best to do something like that may be version dependent; but I'd probably use VBA or Power Query.

Comment: Seems a bit like homework. Is it homework?

Comment: @FlexYourData No, it is not.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the data is specifically represented in your case, and thus not clear to me what question you are asking.  Are you asking "How do I parse the text `1+2n` in a cell so that I end up with values 1 and 2 that I can interact with using formulas?"  In other words, a text parsing question?  If so, it will be useful to know whether your version of excel has access to the newer TEXTSPLIT functions.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in math, an algebraic term can be represented by a matrix and that matrices are where Excel shines.

So, enter your constants and coefficients into a range, then if you want to display as a formula that you might see in a math textbook or paper, you can use text concatenation to do so.

For example, if we take your examples and put them in columns A and B, we can display the math using the formula in column C:

```
=TEXT(formula!$A3,"#")&IF(formula!$B3>0,"+","-")&TEXT(formula!$B3,"#")&LEFT(formula!$B$2,1)
```

While I'm not suggesting that this formula will work for every collection of algebraic terms you have, it should show you a pattern you can use. You can of course concatenate parentheses and other terms as you wish.

[image]

This way, we can perform math on the matrix of coefficients exactly as you would do with matrix algebra.

So, to add the three formulas, we use the SUM function on columns A and B, which gives us the constant and n-coefficient of the result. We can then use the same formula in cell C7 to display the result in math terms.

The benefit of doing it this way is that if and when you need to perform more complex math, such as matrix manipulation, then you can benefit from functions such as MMULT, MINVERSE and so on.

Comment: I'm "respectfully confused" by your approach.  If we already know the value of the constant and coefficient, the C3 would simply be `=A3&"+"&B3&"n"` if the terms are always additive.  If the coefficients can be pos or neg, then it would be `=A3&TEXT(B3,"+#;-#")&"n"`. I'm not sure where all the rest of that is going.

Comment: I've been working in PQ more recently, so was simply trying to explicitly cast the numbers rather than remember that Excel will implicitly cast on concat. Thanks for the addendum. Oh, and my intent was to tie the coefficient to the column header such that the range can be expanded easily and the formulas just dragged across for other terms (rather than hard-coding the "n" in the formula).